# how to search nodes with based on different node properties in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am developing an application using nodejs and Neo4j. I have a node: person which has properties like name, city and school. now I want to provide a search feature where he/she search the person details by name or city or school or either of the combination. So is there a way I can achieve this in neo4j

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

For example, to find `Person` nodes with a specify `name` and `city`, you can use this Cypher query:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.name = 'KMJ' AND p.city = 'Noida'
RETURN p;
```

Since you seem to be learning neo4j, see the [getting started](https://neo4j.com/developer/get-started/) page for some tutorials.

Comment: I apologize, it seems I didn't put the question correctly. what I want is how can I pass the searched value as a parameter in my query from my backend so that it checks all the property of the node and send the matched node. for example, my current query is `.run('Match(n:person {name:{nameParam}}) Return(n)',{nameParam:searchedvalue})`  right now I am only searching by name but I want that user can also search by city and school.

Comment: Thanks, I had figured it out we can do like: `.run('Match(n:person ) WHERE n.name =  $nameParam OR n.city =  $nameParam OR n.school =  $nameParam Return(n)',{nameParam:searchedvalue})`

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following query:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.name = $name AND p.city = $city AND p.school=$school
RETURN p {.name, .city, .school}
UNION
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.name = $name OR p.city = $city OR p.school=$school
RETURN p {.name, .city, .school}
```

Where: $name, $city and $school are the parameters that you would pass in, coming from your front-end.
Also, using UNION between 2 MATCH statements you have the following advantages:

- your duplicates are removed
- the best matches would be your first results, considering the best match is the result meeting all 3 criteria: name, city, school
- the query will execute fast if you don't have a large set of data
- readable query, having the 2 MATCH statements separated.

Reference for UNION: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/union/#union-combine-queries-remove-duplicates

Hope this helps!